# Which platforms does Apache Cordova support?

Tags: apache, cordova, platform

which platforms are officaly supported by cordova? I got two different information on this form the cordova website.

The about section says: iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone, Palm WebOS, Bada, and Symbian (http://cordova.apache.org/#about)

The doc says: Amazon Fire OS, Android, BlackBerry, Firefox OS, iOS, Ubuntu, Windows Phone 8, Windows, Tizen (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_support_index.md.html#Platform%20Support)

Comment: Currently cordova supports amazon-fireos, blackberry10, browser, firefoxos, android and ios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Platform Supports :

- Android
- BlackBerry 10
- iOS
- Ubuntu
- Windows Phone 8
- Windows
- OSx

Platform support at a glance is shown [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/support/index.html)

Also Platform guide is available [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/)

Comment: Why does they say in their about page that they also support Bada, WebOS and Symbian? I don't get that.

Comment: @maiq please recheck the support link

Comment: So what is the deal with this http://cordova.apache.org/#about. This is their own product, Are they nit sure which platforms they are supporting?

Comment: they were supported in older versions of phonegap. you can use that older version, but they no longer maintain or improve the code for that platforms

Comment: Thanks  jcesarmobile for the clarification!